# Hide only first image in Wordpress post

Tags: php, css, wordpress, facebook-opengraph

I have a an issue when sharing an article to Facebook. Facebook pick a random thumbnail from my images. The issue is Facebook wants a 200px X 200px thumbnail and my feature image size happens to be 150x150. The layout of the site is designed to fit 150x150 so I do not want to make the image any bigger. As a test I have tried 200x200 and fb pulls the correct image.

However when I add a 200x200 image in the post facebook grabs the correct image. I don't mind adding the image to the post as I can do text wrap around and everything looks ok on the desktop site. However on the 'WPTouch pro' mobile theme I am stuck with a big image on the post.

Can I hide the image from the mobile page or both ??

Any work around solution are welcomed...

Answer (score 0):

you can add below code

```
$useragent=$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
   if(preg_match('/android|avantgo|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|symbian|tre
      //hide image
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply much appreciated... Sorry I a, a n00b. Can you describe in a bit more detail... Do I add it to header.php or where? Do I am it on the mobile theme or standard site?? Thanks again Bhumi

Comment: you just need to place this image into this condition or just create one function and call function where you require

Comment: I want to use it every time... I do no know how to creat function? Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Go ahead and give the image a class then hide it set the display to none through css.

For example: `<img src="http://img.jpg" class="hide"/>`

Then in your css

```
.hide{
display: none;
}
```

If you want to only hide it when your in wp-touch then you have to see if wp-touch attaches a specific class to the body which I quite sure it does. If you find that out you can attach the class to .hide and then it will only hide the image on wp-touch.

Comment: Hello Casheghian,thanks for your reply. It worked great on the desktop site. Thank you!! I also need it to work for wptouch mobile site. Are you saying to look in the style.css on the wptouch?? Sorry bit of a n00b!!

Comment: Just to confirm, it hides pic on desktop page but sadly doesn't follow through to hide on wptouch

Comment: Ok found the body in style.css for wptouch... Pasted into body as follows...     
/* @group Global General */
body {
 -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
 position: relative;
}

.hide{
display: none;
}

.alignleft {
 float: left;
 margin-right: 15px;
 margin-bottom: 15px;

}

.aligncenter,.alignnone {
 text-align: center !important;
 margin-left: auto !important;
 margin-right: auto !important;
 float: none !important;
 display: block !important;
}

Comment: Sorry looks a bit messy as there is no formatting. No luck on mobile site tho... am I missing anything?? Thanks again